# How to fix 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined' in React

Tags: reactjs, map-function

Hello I am new in React and trying to display the array called Todo that I have created in state, However I get the error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined". Can you please tell me where I have done wrong?

Here is my code

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Todos from './component/Todos.js';
import './App.css'

class App extends Component {
  state={
    todos:[
        {
            id: 1,
            title:'Star Wars',
            point:9,
            watched: true
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            title:'Into the Wild',
            point:null,
            watched: false
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            title:'Enter the Void',
            point:6,
            watched: true
        },
        {
            id: 4,
            title:'Tschick',
            point:7.5,
            watched: true
        }
    ]
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
       <Todos />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Todo.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';


class Todos extends Component {

  render() {

    return this.props.todos.map((todo) => (
        <div>
        <h3>{todo.title}</h3>
        </div>
    ));
  }
}


export default Todos;
```

[The error that I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rE2sa.jpg)

Comment: `Todos` is expecting a `todos` props but you didn't pass it from your `App`. Just change it to `<Todos todos={this.state.todos}/>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't passing the `todos` variable to your component.

You must pass in a property like so:

```
<Todos todos={this.state.todos} />
```

Comment: thanks I thought when I call Todos like this <Todos /> it will run on app.js and since its return is return this.props.todos.map((todo) this will get the state and the array in it called todos

Comment: The component only "knows" about properties in its own class, so you need to pass down data from parent components that you want available in the children.

Answer (score 0):

In your `App.js` call the todos from the state

`<Todos todos={this.state.todos}/>`

It should work fine after that